# How to break an Integer[] arr in more than one interger[] arrs in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a comma separated string of IDs. I want to break this comma separated string in more than one strings if total no. of IDs are greater than 500.

What I can do:
I can convert this string in to integer array and then test it's size. Break than array in more than one arrays, and re-convert them in comma separated strings.

My code so far:

```
 Integer[] empIdInt = null;
     String tokens[]=Application.splitstr(outerArray, ",");
                      if(!ErmUtil.isNull(tokens) && tokens.length>0){       
                          empIdInt=new Integer[tokens.length];
                          for(int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++){
                              empIdInt[i]=Integer.valueOf(tokens[i]);
                          } 
                      }
```

Questions

1. is it right approach to tackle this problem?
2. if yes,how to break integer[] array in more than one arrays?
3. if no, what should i do?

Edit:
input : "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11" //list of ids;

I want to break them more than one string if no. of ids is greater than let's say 3. As we it's 10 i.e total no. of ids. so output might be

Output "1,2,3" //1st string
       "4,5,6" //2nd string
       "7,8,9" //3rd string
       "10"    //4th string

Comment: what is your question exactly? what is your expected output from "comma separated string"?

Comment: and what should be the output?

Comment: I have edited question properly, Sorry pressed enter key by mistake.

Comment: see my answer, it will give exact output which you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have use `List<String>` to store your data and as per count i have use [**List.subList(fromIndex,toIndex)**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)) method to get subList from main List.

Try below code :

```
        String str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15";
        String[] ar_str = str.split(",");
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(ar_str);

        int count = 4;
        int fromIndex = 0;
        int toIndex = count;
        for(int i=0;i<list.size()/count;i++){
            fromIndex = i * count;
            toIndex = fromIndex + count;
            List<String> temp = list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
            System.out.println(temp); //Convert List into comma separated String
        }
        if(list.size()%count > 0){
            System.out.println(list.subList(toIndex, list.size()));
        }
```

**OutPut**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
[13, 14, 15]
```

May this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is a good option to convert it into integer and then count the integers when you can do the same by counting the "," (commas) in your input string.Use StringUtils class of apache which would make your task easier.Here I have assumed list size as 2,you will have to change it too 500 for your case.Try this :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
        List<String> strList=new ArrayList<String>();
        while (StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(input, ",", 2) != -1) {

            String s1 = input.substring(0, StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(input, ",", 2));
            String leftover = input.substring(StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(input, ",", 2) + 1);
            input = leftover;
            strList.add(s1);
        }
        if(input!=""){
            //for leftover strings which are less than your specified list size
            strList.add(input);
        }
        System.out.println(strList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static List<String> breakStrings(String idListString) {
    int limit = 3;
    char separator = ',';
    String[] idList = idListString.split("\\" + separator);
    List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (idList != null && idList.length > 3) {
        int j = 0;
        int index = 0;
        StringBuffer oneList = null;

        while (j < idList.length) {
            oneList = new StringBuffer();

            for (int i = 0; i < limit && index < idList.length; i++) {
                boolean isLast = (i + 1) == limit
                        || (index + 1) == idList.length;
                oneList.append(idList[index++]);
                if (!isLast) {
                    oneList.append(separator);
                }
            }

            finalList.add(oneList.toString());
            j += limit;
        }
    } else {
        finalList.add(idListString);
    }

    return finalList;
}
```

This will give you list of final strings according to your requirement. Hope this will help you.

Comment: nice work :) ,what do you think about navish sharma's ans(complexity wise).

Comment: You can test with very big string and note down the time taken for both answers. This is the only correct way to check performance :) and also post your analysis here.

Comment: Its using third party API. You need to look into those methods as well to check performance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
int[] test={10212,10202,11000,11000,11010};
ArrayList<Integer> test2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();


for(int i = test.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
    int temp = test[i];
    while(temp>0){
        test2.add(0, temp%10);  //place low order digit in array
        temp = temp /10;        //remove low order digit from temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but don't think it will solve the problem. what whould I do with test2? what I want to do is break 'int[] test={10212,10202,11000,11000,11010}'  to int[] one={10212,10202 },int[] two={11000,11000},int[] three={11010}

Answer (score 0):

To get the count of ID in string and divide it into multiple Integer arrays you can do something like this.

```
    String str = "1234,567,123,4567,890";
    String strArray[] = str.split(",");

    if (strArray.length > 500) {
        Integer[][] ids = new Integer[300][2];
        int j = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (String s : strArray) {
            if (i < 2) {
                ids[j][i] = Integer.parseInt(s);
            } else {
                i = 0;
                j = j + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```